# Reference function parameters in an if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, comparison

I'm working on a JS exercise that's basically a function that plays out a match of rock, paper, scissors and declares a winner based on which player had what. Now I've got a completely working program with this:

```
const rps = (p1, p2) => {
    var r = "rock";
    var p = "paper";
    var s = "scissors";

  if(p1 == r && p2 == s || p1 == s && p2 == p || p1 == p && p2 == r){
    return "Player 1 won!";
  }
  else if (p1 == s && p2 == r || p1 == p && p2 == s || p1 == r && p2 == p){
    return "Player 2 won!";
  }
  else if (p1 === p2){
    return "Draw!";
  }
};

console.log(rps("rock","scissors"));
```

I know it's not very pretty but, I'm still learning the ropes. So with this in mind I was wondering if there was a way to dry up the code a bit more by doing something like this for example:

```
const rps = (p1, p2) => {
    var r = "rock";
    var p = "paper";
    var s = "scissors";

 if ((r,s) || (s,p) || (p,r)){
  return "Player 1 won!";
 }
 else if((s,r) || (p,s) || (r,p)){
  return "Player 2 won!";
 }
 else if (p1 === p2){
  return "Draw";
     }
 };

 console.log(rps("rock","scissors"));
```

Something where it would take the variables and use the function parameters as designated spots during the comparisons. I've run the above script and was pretty surprised it actually returned anything, I figured it would throw an error. But...it always returns "Player 1 won" regardless of what strings I'm using in the function call (even when testing for a draw).

Is it possible to do something like that or am I way off base here?

=== EDIT ===

Thought I'd add my speed test results here for better reading. As I mentioned in a comment down below I tested each script 100k times for 3 rounds and returned the completion time via console.time()

Here's my testing loop if anyone is curious:

```
console.time("speed test");

for (var i = 1; i < 100000; i++) {
    rps("scissors","scissors");
}

console.timeEnd("speed test");
```

=== UPDATE ===

Tested locally on my machine (WAMP server) rather than Cloud9's terminal and the speeds were way better:

Here are the results for ("rock, paper"):

```
Cloud9
if/else script --> 4.091ms, 4.228ms, 4.698ms
case script --> 24.844ms, 31.974ms, 20.763ms
table script --> 68.934ms, 86.619ms, 51.805ms

Local
if/else script --> 4.412ms, 4.160ms, 4.374ms
case script --> 6.347ms, 5.551ms, 5.478ms
table script --> 18.093ms, 18.664ms, 19.065ms
```

Here are the results for ("scissors", "scissors"):

```
Cloud9
if/else script --> 4.351ms, 4.214ms, 5.023ms
case script --> 28.387ms, 19.079ms, 29.333ms
table script --> 62.740ms, 59.410ms, 70.401ms

Local
if/else script --> 5.743ms, 5.262ms, 4.858ms
case script --> 5.685ms, 6.447ms, 4.503ms
table script --> 27.116ms, 25.780ms, 24.467ms
```

Performance-wise it seems like the if/else and case methods are extremely close in speed at least locally.

Comment: If you assign a string to r ( `r = "hello";`) and type `r` and `return` in the console, the console will log "hello". Surprisingly, it will log the same if you type `( r )` into the console. But JavaSript gets a bit confused when you do `( r , s )` when both are assigned strings. The output is actually the value of the second variable. Now if you put that into an if statement like you have: `if( (r,s) )` everything inside the outer parentheses is coerced into a Boolean value. Since a string is returned by `(r,s)`, that will evacuate as true in the if statement.

Comment: As you can tell, the others will also evaluate to true. I couldn't put that in answer because you didn't directly ask about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible: **Yes**, are you way off base: **No**.

This is a classic Matrix mathematics setup. The cool part is that you defined the Matrix in your errant ways with your attempt at the `if` statement. If you look at the if statement you'll see the combinations come right out at you. The good news is that this one is really easy to rationalize because it turns out that all we have to deal with is a very small Cartesian coordinate system. The coordinate system based upon your definitions above is in the code sample below. Run the sample to see the table.

The code consists of simple lookup tables.

1. Determine a value for each player's tool (array index[0,1,2])
2. Combine them into a string such as "01" or "20"

   - Player1's number will always be first and wins with 02, 21 & 10
3. Convert them to an integer (that's what the + sign does)
4. Find the resulting integer in our lookup tables.  4.

I hope this was instructive and helpful and not to direct of a solution.

```js
function RPS(p1Tool, p2Tool) {
  const tools = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
  const p1Wins = [2,21,10];
  const p2Wins = [20,12,1];
  const draw = [0,11,22];
  // p1Tool = 'rock' returns 0, p2Tool = 'scissors' returns 2 
  const winner = +(tools.indexOf(p1Tool) + tools.indexOf(p2Tool));
  // look up the results in our matrixes
  return (p1Wins.includes(winner))
          ? 'Player 1'
          : (p2Wins.includes(winner))
             ? 'Player 2'
             : 'No One';
 } 
let winner = RPS('rock', 'scissors');

alert(winner + ' wins!');
```

```html
<TABLE border="1">
  <TH></TH><TH>R(0)</TH><TH>P(1)</TH><TH>S(2)</TH>
  <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
    <TD>R(0)</TD>
    <TD>D</TD>
    <TD>P</TD>
    <TD>R</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
    <TD>P(1)</TD>
    <TD>P</TD>
    <TD>D</TD>
    <TD>S</TD>
  </TR>
  <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
    <TD>S(2)</TD>
    <TD>R</TD>
    <TD>S</TD>
    <TD>D</TD>
  </TR>
</TABLE>
<span>Think Cartesian Coordinates</span>
```

Comment: you are fantastic! It took me a few read-throughs to wrap my head around using a look up table (I've heard the terminology but never actually researched it) but the way you laid it all out is perfect. And I see what you mean by the coords (especially with the table representation), reminds me a little of a punnet square lol. Thanks so much for the detailed explanation (including the comments about why things like ( (r,s) ) were returning something. You've given me lots of food for thought !

Comment: Awesome. thanks so much for taking the time to express your gratitude. I really enjoy helping. Its nice for you to notice.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that I think is pretty simple (sorry if it isn't formatted perfectly):

```
<html>

<script language=javascript>

    const r = 1;
    const p = 10;
    const s = 100;

function rps (p1, p2) {
//alert (p1);
//alert (p2);
var num = Math.abs(p1 - p2);  // rock wins when the difference is 99
alert (num);                  // scissors when it is 90
                              // paper when it is 9
 switch (num) {
     case 9:
         // Paper wins!
         alert ("Paper wins!");
          break;
     case 90:
         // Scissors wins!
         alert ("Scissors wins!");
         break;
     case 99:
         // Rock wins!
         alert ("Rock wins!");
         break;
     default:
         // It is a tie!
         alert ("It is a tie!");
         break;
     }
}

function runit() {
    //alert (r);
    //alert (p);
    //alert (s);
    rps(r,p);
    rps(p,r);
    rps(r,s);
    rps(s,r);
    rps(p,s);
    rps(s,p);
    rps(r,r);
    rps(p,p);
    rps(s,s);
} 

</script>

<body onload="runit()">
been so long

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The real test, of course, would be to run each of the different methods ten thousand times and see which operates the fastest.

Comment: Interesting...I just looked up the functionality of Math.abs. That's pretty cool that it returns absolute values, because the first thing that came to mind after looking over your code was "But what if you get a negative?". But the method takes care of that. I gotta say it's a very clean simple solution. And I'd love to test them all against each other. Thanks @J.Doe!

Comment: Thanks, Danielle.  Avoiding those string comparisons is going to be significant.  Remember, what looks like one line of code is often a whole lot more.

Comment: Don't know if you're interested @J.Doe but I just ran all three via console.time. I ran each 100k times, 3 tests each and here are the results:  if/else script --> 4.091ms, 4.228ms, 4.698ms.  case script --> 24.844ms, 31.974ms, 20.768ms.   table script --> 68.934ms, 86.619ms, 51.805ms. Apparently a good old fashioned if/else runs the fastest? You were absolutely right about beauty over function. I did these tests in Chrome (desktop) and Cloud9 btw.

Comment: I should also add I was testing all three scripts with only a single comparison of ("rock, "paper"). It would be interesting to test them with randomly generated parameters but that's way above my knowledge at this point. Something for the future definitely.

Comment: Great work, Danielle!!  Thanks for sharing!  Gonna upvote your question because of your effort with the responses.  Definitely use other combinations because they don’t all get tested out at the same place, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Danielle, if you don’t mind, run the test with (scissors,scissors), as that would seem to be your worst case scenario, and put those results up. TIA!

Comment: Sorry, I am new here, so I can’t chat, but after this if you really wanted to explore some things, get rid of the switch and make it an if-else construct, and then get rid of math.abs and just check for negative or positive in the if-else.  The math.abs function could be more expensive than the additional comparison, and switch is likely more expensive than if-else.  Best.

Comment: Yeah I'll definitely have to mess around with these scripts. And I've added the results for (scissors, scissors) in my original post, seems there were some increases and decreases but nothing too huge.

Comment: Danielle, I looked at times a little and I did not see the fives times difference that you obtained.  Are the two routines each doing the same data output?

Comment: I believe so? I mean the only thing I changed between the two sets of testing rounds was what it was being tested with. Meaning ("rock", "paper") vs ("scissors", "scissors"). I could post each exact script I'm working with if that helps? Could be Cloud9 too, maybe I should run everything again locally and see if that changes the speed.

Comment: Yep it was totally Cloud9. Check my updated speed results from testing on my local machine. They're way better and I suspect closer to what you were probably getting.

Comment: As you see, writing output is time consuming.

Comment: Absolutely. And thanks again for all your help and suggestions J.Doe! I've learned a lot from you and @Randy about different ways to run comparisons and their costs. It's been fun!

Answer (score 0):

In your second routine, you never even use the variables that are passed in to determine what they are.  How do you expect it to determine anything besides the result it is producing, which you don’t at all understand why it is producing it.   (r,s) and probably all of the similar conditions are evaluating to ‘true’ probably only because they are not zero, and as soon as you have ‘true’ it kicks out, so it happens that way every time.

Comment: You didn't address the question: _**_Is it possible to do something like that or am I way off base here?**_

Comment: The second routine was purely for example purposes so I could hopefully get my idea across. Sort of a conceptual script to see if something like that was even possible (or anywhere close to it). And as I mentioned before I'm still learning. But thanks at least for mentioning why the second script is returning the way it is.

Comment: My answer addressed why it was giving the result is was.  I would caution against beauty over function, but below I will give the answer the way I would go about something that was maybe easier to read, if not understand.

Comment: Hey @Randy, I meant to tell you before, what you have done here is really cool.